# How to configure Graylog Plugin on bootstrap (non interactive)?

Tags: docker, configuration, graylog

I setup a Graylog server based on the [official Graylog 3 Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/graylog/graylog) and added the [SSO plugin](https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-plugin-auth-sso). In principle it works but I have to configure the SSO headers using the UI after each container start.

I [see the options](https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.3/pages/installation/docker.html#configuration) to configure Graylog itself using either a `server.conf` file or environment variables. But I cannot find any way to configure the plugin upfront to get a final image for automatic deployment.

Is there any way to configure Graylog plugins using special config file entries, prefixed environment variables or separate config files?

Answer (score 0):

If you create you're own shell script to update files/settings, you can create a new image based on the original (a new `Dockerfile`), which, when started, will run the script, modify any relevant settings and start the application-server. Even better if you can have the script take inputs which you can supply as environment variables to the docker container.

Comment: The problem is: what files/settings to update. I haven’t found any for the plugins or roles

Comment: seems like you can configure the service via HTTP requests. So it may be possible to use simple curl requests in a script at startup https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-plugin-auth-sso#development

Comment: There's an example here: https://docs.graylog.org/en/3.3/pages/installation/docker.html#plugins for the Dockerfile you'd need. Then you just need to add `RUN` to the image you create

Comment: I have a working Dockerfile adding the plugins based on the official one, that’s not the problem. Using the HTTP API is an option, but the last/worst from my opinion as I would have to start the server, wait for it in another process and use curl afterwards - using supervisors e.g.. Beside that I would need admin authentication for that… You are right, that could work but it is really ugly. I think Graylog hates DevOps.

Comment: Very true - I'd try to understand the codebase - its very small. https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog-plugin-auth-sso/blob/master/src/main/java/org/graylog/plugins/auth/sso/SsoConfigResource.java this looks like a good starting point. I'm not sure if everything is set in memory or read from files. Seems likely you could override any file settings using a bash script or by mounting a server.conf file from your local file system

Comment: There are no entries in the server.conf file for the plugin. I have a bad feeling Graylog either does not support conf file entries for plugins or none of the plugins use it (it is not only about the SSO plugin).